# gcc linker cannot find header file source

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors

so essentially I'm trying to use a third party library like so:

```
#include <libexif/exif-data.h>
```

in terminal i tried the following command and several variations of it:

gcc -I "/usr/include/libexif" -c write-exif.c -o write

but every time it says file/directory does not exist.

I know I'm missing something pretty simple, so any help is appreciated.

NOTE: write-exif.c is stand alone and has the main() function within it. It does not use any other external library.

Comment: Have you tried `#include <exif-data.h>`?

Comment: tried that, doesn't recognize it.

Also, if try generic "gcc -Wall -o write write-exif.c -lm", I get "undefined references".

Comment: Post the exact error message, and the output of `ls -alF /usr/include/libexif/exif-data.h`. Also post the command you use to link, where you specify the actual library. Your "generic" `gcc -Wall -o write write-exif.c -lm` in your comment doesn't specify the library, which is why you're getting undefined references.

Comment: Here it is:

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8738 2012-07-19 11:58 /usr/include/libexif/exif-data.h

Comment: @TauseefLatif: You say "It does not use any other external library" in your updated question, but you still start it off by saying you are "trying to use a third party library". These two things can't both be true.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant this is the only third party library I'm trying to use. There is no other source of error.

Comment: @TauseefLatif: You still haven't posted the command you're using to link, after you compile `write-exif.c`. rslemos's comment seems like it solves your `#include` problem.

Comment: I tries @rslemos 's idea, but that didn't work.

Comment: @TauseefLatif: If you got undefined reference errors, then it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the libraries.

Try this:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/libexif write-exif.c -o write /path/to/library/libexif.a
```

Alternatively:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/libexif -L/path/to/library write-exif.c -o write -lexif
```

Edit: I edited the answer cause I read a lowercase L instead of an uppercase i after gcc. I should have figured, given the path (include) that it was an uppercase i... My bad.

Edit2: from the question title, I thought it was a linker problem. I see not that it's not a linker problem, but a compilation error (missing header). In this case, I agree with the comment that says to try to include 'exif-data.h' rather than 'libefix/efix-data.h'. You are already giving the full path with the -I flag, so you should not include the libefix directory in the include.

Comment: that kind of worked! I suppose it is the '-lexif' part. I was able to leave out the '-L/path...'.

But what is this exactly doing?

(btw, libexif was just the folder. I'm trying to include exfi-data.h)

Comment: The header contains only the 'declaration' of the functions/classes in efix. The actual implementation is in the library. You need to tell the linker to link that library, so that gcc can actually give a face to all those functions/classes defined in the header.

The fact that you didn't need the -L... is because that library is in a folder that gcc scans automatically (probabli is in /usr/lib). If it were in a different folder (such as your home), you probably would have needed it.

Comment: You are right, it seems to work with just "gcc -c write-exif.c -o write -lexif"

Comment: Actually I'm still not sure what -lexif is doing. I don't have anything named just 'exif'.

Comment: I know you don't. The flag -lX looks for the library libX.a or libX.so (I don't remember which one is scanned for first). It's a shortcut for libX.a, look for that file, you should find it.